# how to download files to a default dir without poping an option window in Flex/Air?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I'm writing a app with Flex/air,and i need a function that downloading files to the default dir without  a pop-up window.i tried to use ftp instead of http but found it's not supported by air.how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Where are you going with this?

Comment: I need this: the user installs my flex application,and click a download button for some resource,and the downloading just starts and completes without requiring any other operation such as download comfirming .

Comment: http://www.baidu.com how to print a link in comment,who can tell me,with my own link name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be possible in AIR.  I don't know if there's a direct API approach, but you should be able to load the bytes into memory and then flush them into a file.  In pseudo-pseudo-code using [File](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/filesystem/File.html) and [FileStream](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html):

```
// get the bytes
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.load("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
...
var bytes:ByteArray = loader.data;

// get the file in the correct location
var f:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("myfile.txt");

// write the file
var fs:FileStream = new FileStream(f, FileMode.WRITE);
fs.writeBytes(bytes);
fs.close();
```

There are a [few examples](http://www.google.com/search?q=using+file+filestream+air) out there to look at.

None of this is possible in Flash Player because of the security limits @viatropos suggests.

Comment: Finally this turns out to be a solution:)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do that as it's a Security violation.  The user must be prompted with a download window so they can choose the directory.  I think the thinking goes "if you don't prompt the user, then a Flash/Flex app could download a bunch of junk to their computer without their permission", and that would make adobe look bad :/.  I wish you could though.

You can, however, download it using a server side script without asking the user for permission.  I do that with ruby to accomplish what you're describing.

Hope that helps,
Lance

Comment: thank u for ur quick reply.But i wonder how a server side script can put sth to local quietly?i use python and php in my work,and find it difficult to do that with them:(

Answer (score 0):

You can but only air version because you have to use FileStream

```
        var ff:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("sample.dwg");
        var u:String = obj_l.d1.selectedItem.data + "" + obj_l.d2.selectedItem.label;
        var ll3:URLLoader = new URLLoader ();
        u = GETURL() + u;
        rr.url = u;
        //ff.download(rr);
        ll3.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
        ll3.load(rr);
        ll3.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE , function (e:Event):void {
            var stream:FileStream = new FileStream ();
            stream.open(ff,FileMode.WRITE);
            stream.writeBytes(ll3.data);
        });
```